# Set current rotation of an object to its default

Tags: modeling

I have built a rocket model with it upright, but its rotation is off.
[image]

I want to change all the values to 0 so it can be a more manageable "default" state. The thing is, when I change them to 0, the model flips. I'm trying to keep the model the way it is, but set the XYZ rotation to 0

Comment: CTRL-A to apply the rotation?

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was that simple. I'm still a beginner so thanks!

Comment: No problem. As they say, we were all beginners once.